# How to disable Slide Icon on last page in Flutter Liquid Swipe?

Tags: flutter

Is there any way to disable the slide icon when you reach last page of Liquid Swipe while not looping?

`enableSlideIcon: false,` //disables slide icon on all pages

I want to hide it from last page only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
Step 1: You can use `bool slideIcon` to control 
Step 2: In `pageChangeCallback`, compare `pages.length` with `lpage` then do `setState`

code snippet

```
bool slideIcon = true;
...
LiquidSwipe(
              enableSlideIcon: slideIcon,
...           
pageChangeCallback(int lpage) {
    setState(() {
      if (lpage == pages.length - 1) {
        slideIcon = false;
      } else {
        slideIcon = true;
      }
      page = lpage;
    });
  }
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:liquid_swipe/liquid_swipe.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MyApp(),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  static final style = TextStyle(
    fontSize: 30,
    fontFamily: "Billy",
    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
  );

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  int page = 0;
  LiquidController liquidController;
  UpdateType updateType;
  bool slideIcon = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    liquidController = LiquidController();
    super.initState();
  }

  final pages = [
    Container(
      color: Colors.pink,
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: <Widget>[
          Image.network(
            'https://picsum.photos/250?image=9',
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          ),
          Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                "Hi",
                style: MyApp.style,
              ),
              Text(
                "It's Me",
                style: MyApp.style,
              ),
              Text(
                "Sahdeep",
                style: MyApp.style,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
    Container(
      color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: <Widget>[
          Image.network(
            'https://picsum.photos/250?image=10',
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          ),
          Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                "Take a",
                style: MyApp.style,
              ),
              Text(
                "look at",
                style: MyApp.style,
              ),
              Text(
                "Liquid Swipe",
                style: MyApp.style,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
    Container(
      color: Colors.greenAccent,
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: <Widget>[
          Image.network(
            'https://picsum.photos/250?image=11',
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          ),
          Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                "Liked?",
                style: MyApp.style,
              ),
              Text(
                "Fork!",
                style: MyApp.style,
              ),
              Text(
                "Give Star!",
                style: MyApp.style,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
    Container(
      color: Colors.yellowAccent,
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: <Widget>[
          Image.network(
            'https://picsum.photos/250?image=12',
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          ),
          Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                "Can be",
                style: MyApp.style,
              ),
              Text(
                "Used for",
                style: MyApp.style,
              ),
              Text(
                "Onboarding Design",
                style: MyApp.style,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
    Container(
      color: Colors.redAccent,
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: <Widget>[
          Image.network(
            'https://picsum.photos/250?image=13',
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          ),
          Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                "Do",
                style: MyApp.style,
              ),
              Text(
                "Try it",
                style: MyApp.style,
              ),
              Text(
                "Thank You",
                style: MyApp.style,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ];

  Widget _buildDot(int index) {
    double selectedness = Curves.easeOut.transform(
      max(
        0.0,
        1.0 - ((page ?? 0) - index).abs(),
      ),
    );
    double zoom = 1.0 + (2.0 - 1.0) * selectedness;
    return Container(
      width: 25.0,
      child: Center(
        child: Material(
          color: Colors.white,
          type: MaterialType.circle,
          child: Container(
            width: 8.0 * zoom,
            height: 8.0 * zoom,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            LiquidSwipe(
              enableSlideIcon: slideIcon,
              pages: pages,
              onPageChangeCallback: pageChangeCallback,
              waveType: WaveType.liquidReveal,
              liquidController: liquidController,
              ignoreUserGestureWhileAnimating: true,
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(child: SizedBox()),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: List<Widget>.generate(pages.length, _buildDot),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
                child: FlatButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    liquidController.animateToPage(
                        page: pages.length - 1, duration: 500);
                  },
                  child: Text("Skip to End"),
                  color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.01),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
                child: FlatButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    liquidController.jumpToPage(
                        page: liquidController.currentPage + 1);
                  },
                  child: Text("Next"),
                  color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.01),
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  pageChangeCallback(int lpage) {
    setState(() {
      if (lpage == pages.length - 1) {
        slideIcon = false;
      } else {
        slideIcon = true;
      }
      page = lpage;
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: `enableSlideIcon` looks to be deprecated/removed from the latest version. For future readers, you can set `slideIconWidget` to null if you do not want the icon to be shown. The remaining logic stays the same.